# Android logging Application launch intent logging

Tags: android

Is there a way to get the `Intent`, or any other information about how the app was launched (`BroadcastReceiver`,`Service`,`Activity`), within the `Application`, without adding code to all the class that can lunch the app (keep in mind that there are library class that I can't override.

I couldn't find anything within the `Context` interface, that could retrieve any data about that.
I thought about using a class loader, and query somehow what classes have been loaded to memory.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get the Intent, or any other information about how the app was lunched (BroadcastReceiver,Service,Activity), within the Application, without adding code to all the class that can lunch the app (keep in mind that there are library class that I cant override.

On API Level 14+, your `Application` can call `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()`, after which it will be called for all lifecycle methods on activities within your app. Using that, you can call `getIntent()` on the `Activity` that is supplied to your callback.

However:

- That is only for API Level 14+
- That is only for activities, not other components
- Since `onNewIntent()` is not included in the callbacks, you can only readily get the original `Intent` that started the activity, not any `Intent` that caused an existing instance to come back to the foreground, if that matters

Comment: Well, since its just actives its not that useful in my case.